What happens to the noise in the predictive distribution
In PILCO (Probabilistic Inference for Learning COntrol) the setup is that we have a dynamics model where the inputs are $[x_t, u_t]\in \mathbb{R}^{F+D}$ and the targets are the differences $\Delta_t = x_{t+1} - x_t$. The system is modelled with a Gaussian Process $f$ with mean function $m\equiv 0$ and squared exponential kernel $k(\cdot, \cdot)$.
As I understand it then, we are saying that
$$\Delta_t = f(x_t, u_t) + w\quad w\sim N(0, I_{\epsilon}) \tag{*}$$
with $w$ representing noise.
To find $p(x_{t+1})$ (which is our main goal) we need to find the distribution of $\Delta_t$. Most of the articles on PILCO that I can find tries to first argue that doing it analytically is not possible. They say that
$$p(\Delta_t) = \iint p(f(\hat{x}_t)|\hat{x}_t)p(\hat{x}_t)\ df d\hat{x}_t$$
is analytically intractable (here $\hat{x}_t = [x_t, u_t]$).
My question is how do they get to this integral?

I can only think of writing $p(\Delta_t)$ as:
$$p(\Delta_t) = \iint p(\Delta_{t}|f, \hat{x}_t)p(f|\hat{x}_t)p(\hat{x}_t) \ df d\hat{x}_t$$
which looks close, but from (*) I would expect that $\Delta_t \mid f, \hat{x}_t \sim N(f(\hat{x}_t), I_{\epsilon})$ which looks inconsistent to the first integral above.

Link to original PILCO with integral being eq (9)
Link to follow up article mentioning PILCO, integral eq (8)
